# Read html's elements attributes like an array?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm thinking for develop a web component form, so... I was wondering my self if it's possible read attributes from a html elements. For example:

```
<my-component input="3" data-input='"name", "address", "email"' textarea="1" data-textarea='"mensaje"'></my-component>

<script>
while i <= elementattributes.length{
elementattributes[i] 
} 
</script>
```

I know that I can access through .getAttribute, but this way will take more code... I just want to be something smart :P

Sorry, my english is poor... I hope you can understand what I want to do :P
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use .attributes:

```
document.getElementById("ELEMENT_ID").attributes
```

This will return an object containing each attribute with its associated value. You can then index the attributes array for specific attributes and use .value for it's corresponding value.

Comment: Wow... jajajaja it's so simple... i never imagined got all attributes with the method .attributes :P This is just what I need :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dataset` to get specific `data` attribute

```js
var data = document.querySelector('my-component').dataset.input.split(',');
data.forEach(function(e) {
 console.log(e)
})
```

```html
<my-component input="3" data-input='name,address,email' textarea="1" data-textarea='"mensaje"'></my-component>
```

If you want to return all attributes from element you can use `attributes` which return array-like object, but you can create object with `name-value` from that

```js
var data = document.querySelector('my-component').attributes, attr = {};
Array.from(data).forEach(function(e) {
  attr[e.name] = e.value;
});

console.log(attr['data-input']);
```

```html
<my-component input="3" data-input='name,address,email' textarea="1" data-textarea='mensaje'></my-component>
```

Comment: I think the OP is wanting to get all of the attributes and their values, not just `data-` attribute values

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all of the attributes and their values, you can do something like this:

```js
function getElementAttrs(el) {
  var attributes = [].slice.call(el.attributes);
  return attributes.map(function(attr) {
    return {
      name: attr.name,
      value: attr.value
    }
  });
}

var allAttrs = getElementAttrs(document.querySelector('my-component'));

console.log(allAttrs);
```

```html
<my-component input="3" data-input='name,address,email' textarea="1" data-textarea='"mensaje"'></my-component>
```

The function `getElementAttrs` returns an array of objects to you with attribute name-value pairs as keys on the object so that you can loop over it, or just pull by key.